# Velocity ; Acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

A ball was thrown vertically upwards with a speed of 3m/s. 
The ball reached a highest point before falling down to the ground.
What is the acceleration of the ball at the highest point?

A 0m/s2

B 3m/s2

C 10m/s2

D 30m/s2

The answer is C, but I have no idea how to get that.. Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple question of conceptual understanding. The only force acting on the ball after it is released from the hand is that of the ball's weight due to gravity. Since it is the only force, the consequent acceleration is also the only acceleration. Gravity is being taken to be $10 m/s^2$ in a downward direction. For the answer to be correct, our reference direction must be downward (rather than upward) or the value would be negative.